OFFSET - MATCH with multiple criterias
I need to include another MATCH criteria inside this formula to add it in the Data Validation for a drop down list:
=OFFSET(Data!$Y$1,MATCH(J$4,Data!$X$2:$X$500,0),0,COUNTIF(Data!$X$2:$X$500,J$4))
This is where the other MATCH criteria should be:
MATCH(J$10,Data!$X$2:$X$500,0),0,COUNTIF(Data!$V$2:$V$500,J$10)
I already tried the INDEX formula but it is not working. Any ideas?

It's not clear what you exactly want us to do with the bottom set of formulas; however, depending on your version of excel you can use a countifs formula instead of countif. As for your match, it's too unclear how you expect the inputs to flow through on single-output formula like match.

Have you tried using something like: INDEX(a,MATCH(1st)):INDEX(a,MATCH(2nd))

I tried using it like this but it is not working: =OFFSET(Data!$Y$1,INDEX(MATCH(Data!$X$2:$X$500=J$4)*(Data!$V$2:$V$500=J$10)),0,COUNTIF(Data!$X$2:$X$500,J$4))
